# How can I join different variables into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to  an array that look like this :  `let whatever= ["one,"two","three","four","five"]` out of the divs below.

```
 <div class="randomClass">one</div>
 <div class="randomClass">two</div>
 <div class="randomClass">three</div>
 <div class="randomClass">four</div>
 <div class="randomClass">five</div>
```

How can it be done ?
I've tried `Array.form()` / tried a few things with `random.innerText` . Nothing seems to work

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelector('.randomClass')).map(element => element.innerText)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.randomClass') // get all Dom elements
const elementsArray =  Array.from(elements); // transform into iterable
const final = elementsArray.map(node => node.textContent) // map and get content
```

edit: use of `Array.from` instead of older version

Or as a one-line

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.randomClass')).map(node => node.textContent)
```

Comment: Why not use the `.values()` function?  `document.querySelectorAll('...').values().map(...)`

Comment: It does not work in nodeLists. Unless I did not do it properly

Comment: @ChrisG You can only use values as an iterator in a for...of loop. You would still have to spread it into an array... `[...elements.values()]`

Comment: I used `Array.from` instead of the deconstructor, but I guess both do the same job

Comment: Yeah, I guess there are about 10 different ways to handle that iterator -> array conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all elements with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). It will return elements in an array-like container. You can then convert it into an array and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".randomClass")];
const result = elements.map((ele) => ele.textContent);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="randomClass">one</div>
<div class="randomClass">two</div>
<div class="randomClass">three</div>
<div class="randomClass">four</div>
<div class="randomClass">five</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for elements by that class, spread the elements into an array, and then map them to their text content.

```js
const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('.randomClass')]
  .map(el => el.textContent.trim());

console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="randomClass">one</div>
<div class="randomClass">two</div>
<div class="randomClass">three</div>
<div class="randomClass">four</div>
<div class="randomClass">five</div>
```

If you have hidden content, you can use `innerText` instead of `textContent` to filter your list. Keep in mind that this is more performance-heavy, as it needs to compute rendered styles.

```js
const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('.randomClass')]
  .map(el => el.innerText)
  .filter(text => text !== '');

console.log(values);
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="randomClass">one</div>
<div class="randomClass hidden">two</div>
<div class="randomClass">three</div>
<div class="randomClass hidden">four</div>
<div class="randomClass">five</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("randomClass"))
   .map(em => em.textContent)
```

Explanation:

**Array.from** - create an array of the dom colletion

**document.getElementsByClassName("randomClass")** - get all dom elements with the class "randomClass"

**Array.map** - for every element in the array return the innerText